# Access Sent Messages, Spam folders through IMAP

Tags: java, email, imap

I am trying to read emails present in folders of Gmail. For reading inbox mails i tried:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
    store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect();
    folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

but for reading SPAM or Sent, I should replace INBOX with which keyword?

Comment: Is there a method that returns a list of folders?

Comment: Did you try 'SPAM' and 'SENT'?

Comment: @Keerthivasan: Yes i tried and i got error as: javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: SENT not found

Comment: @immibis: I dont have idea.. but store doesnot have any method for get all folders or list.

Comment: You need to use the LIST command to see the folder list. And if you're going to support non-english accounts, you'll have to look for folder tags, or guess.

Comment: Also, your port should be 993. 995 is the pop3s port.

Comment: You're using Javamail, which does have methods to list the available folders. store.getDefaultFolder().list() or so. Read the fine manual.

Answer (score 0):

If hotmail, use JUNK rather than SPAM.